# What does "Approved By" mean on an invoice?

Tags: freelancing, invoices, self-employment

I am new in the professional word. I'm doing freelance work for an organization, and they need an invoice. All of the invoice templates I can find have this little box on them:

[image: approved by, name, for, date]

And I am unsure of what goes in the places. Here are my guesses:

- Approved by is the title of the person who gave me the work
- Name is that same person's name
- For is the name of the organization
- Date is the date I'm sending the invoice

But I am unsure of every one of those. I'm hoping that this is the right place to ask!

Comment: It means that someone with authority signed off on your invoice as authoritative and that your demand for payment, as documented by your invoice, moves forward toward your goal of being fully paid - a goal which will be achieved when everyone with the requisite authority and responsibility has signed off on your invoice. If it sounds bureaucratic and deliberate, that's because it is bureaucratic and deliberate. They weren't going to liberate your money just on your say-so, right? :)

Comment: Thanks, Vietnhi! So what do I actually put in the boxes? Where my guesses correct?

Comment: You don't get to fill in the boxes! For the same reason that I'd get rich if I got to approve my own invoices :) Submit your invoice to your client. Either your client fills in the boxes because your client has the authority, or your client passes on the invoice to someone in the client's hierarchy who has authority to liberate your money. But you gotta take the first step amd submit that invoice to your client :)

Answer (score 2):

Your invoice should have the following information, more or less:

> Invoice Date
>
> Your name
>
> > Business Address
> >
> > > Phone Email, etc.
>
> Client Business Name
>
> > Client Manager Name (the person you're reporting to)
> >
> > > Client Address
>
> Purchaser Order Number (if one is provided)
>
> Date of work - Description of Work - Hours - Rate - Daily Total
>
> [Above for each block of work, typically a full or partial day]
>
> Expense Date - Expense description - Expense Amount
>
> Total for Invoice
>
> Your signature

The line with the Client Manager's Name is where the manager signs off on (approves) the invoice, before it is forwarded to Accounts Payable.

It is a good idea to describe what you've actually done on a particular day: some people put something like 'IT Services' or 'Software Development'. Better is 'Set up Inventory database, created validation tables, make backup, set up script to back up server at 11:00 PM each night'.  In short, make it possible for you to provide a narrative of what you've been doing over time, so they can see how you're progressing.